# undefined method error in main:Object

Tags: ruby

Please see the code below

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

findtrue = true
count = 0
while findtrue do
  count+=1
  if count 10
    findtrue = false;
  elsif puts count
  end   
end
```

I am getting an error

```
undefined method `count' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Why I am getting this error? Anything to be added in the require section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is caused by the line

```
if count 10
```

this is read by ruby to be

```
if count(10)
```

which tries to call a method called `count`, which does not exist.

I guess what you intended to do was to check if count equals 10. For that you need to add the `==` sign:

```
if count == 10
```

Answer (score 2):

The code `if count 10` is translated to a method call: `if count(10)` and you clearly don't have a `count` method. I suppose you want to use a comparison operator like `if count == 10`.

**Edit:** You should also change `elsif` to `else`:

```
if count == 10
  findtrue = false
else
  puts count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You come from a more traditionale program language looking at your code, in Ruby this can be done clearer and shorter, in short more Rubyish.

First, require 'rubygems' is not necessary for Ruby > v1.9
And the rest can be done with this one line

```
9.times{|count|puts count}
```

or its longer version

```
9.times do |count|
  puts count
  # and do whatever else
end
```

Comment: ...or `9.times(&method(:puts))`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers